# Does $_SESSION[]; create a session

Tags: php

I don't know if `$_SESSION[];` creates a new session I think it does but I don't know;

If it does, should I put `session_set_cookie_params(0);` right before my session variable? like this

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
$_SESSION['name'];
```

Thanks

Comment: No it does not. session_start() does

Answer (score 2):

`session_start();` creates a session. `$_SESSION` just a global dictionary to store necessary values.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

`session_set_cookie_params(0);` gives cookies 0 seconds lifetime. It's simply cookies timeout definition. But there are more optional parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this at the start

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = 'Bob';
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start(); starts / creates session
$_SESSION["sessionname"]=$value; assigns a value
echo $_SESSION["sessionname"]; - returns the value of the session
session_destroy(); -session destroy ends a session and revoves values
session_set_cookie_params(); - allows you to set other parameters for the     session such as lifetime
```

either cookies or sessions can be used to make data available globally but session is more secure as it is stored server side while cookie is stored client side and can accessed by user.  Even session uses a cookie but it only contains an id not the actual value which is stored on the server so session_set_cookie_params() is optional depending on if you want to change other parameters